# Save data from random extraction from DB

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences

I have a simple quiz with random extraction from my DB and I need to save the last data when the user close my app.

When user re-open the app, he should see the last data and after there is the random extraction.

I am thinking to use `SharedPreferences`, but I need to take the last data and restart the random extraction. I have no idea. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Please clarify your question, to exactly what you'd like to know

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly pointed out that you would need to use `SharedPreferences`. If it is a quiz question that you have to store then, assign a unique id to each quiz question (and its options) and store this in your shared preferences. Or just store the question and its list of options in the sharedpreferences and on app open display this and store the output.

After this question is answered you can do the random extraction of the quiz questions.